# Как получить OAuth2 Access Token для неизвестных сервисов?

Tags: imap, oauth2

При разработке своего приложения я столкнулся с проблемой чтения IMAP, для которого требуется авторизация SASL и OAuth2, который требует в своё время "Access Token" для "приложения".
Вопрос: получается, что для всех почтовых сервисов в мире я должен регистрировать свое приложение и получать кучу "Access Toke'ов"? Допустим Google, Microsoft, Yahoo, Mail.ru, Yandex - с этими разберусь руками, но закономерный вопрос, а как быть с сервисами туземцев, например "на каком-нибудь иврите" и всякие неизвестные сервисы типа Timeweb да куча вообще неизвестных мне платформ и частные сервера с OAuth2, которые появляются как грибы.
Существует ли для этого агрегатор какой-нибудь? Где централизованно уже все могут получить единый токен. Да и хранить все эти токены какая-то плохая идея.
Просвятите как вообще работаю такие как ThunderBird и Outlook, а то больше похоже на какаую-то монополизацию на почтовые клиенты. Как с этим борются мелкие разрабы?